# Android: trying to save data but it's being lost on the second onDestroy()

Tags: java, android, save, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

Basically, I am trying to save and load data with my Android app. It works as intended when pressing the home button, and re-entering the app. Even closing the app for the first time through the app manager, it loads fine with the correct data (just one integer at the moment for test purposes). The second time the app is closed through the app manager, the data is lost, even though it's killed using the same method as the first time. Find below the code dealing with anything saving, loading, and the relevant methods.

**Android life cycle methods:**

```
public int setting1 = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    loadData();

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveData();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    saveData();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    saveData();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    loadData();

    updateUnlockables(setting1);
}
```

**Save and Load Methods:**

```
public void saveData(){
    String filename = "icesSave.asv";
    FileOutputStream fos;

    try {
        fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeInt(setting1);
        oos.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void loadData(){
    String filename = "icesSave.asv";
    FileInputStream fis;

    try{
        fis = openFileInput(filename);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
        return;
    }
    try {

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        setting1 = ois.readInt();
        ois.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: try writing saveData(); before the line super. of all onPause, onDestroy and onStop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`saveData()` should be above on `super`

Dont Use `saveData()`  in all 3 method because its same process

```
        @Override
        public void onPause() {
     saveData();
            super.onPause();

        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
 saveData();
            super.onStop();

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
    saveData();
            super.onDestroy();

        }
```

Comment: Yeah this definitely fixed my issue thank you very much. Will update with best answer shortly.

Comment: ALSO PLEASE NOTE: You should only save data on onPause() as shown above. Saving data in all 3 "kill" methods seemed to break the save method (or seemed to write the wrong data when saving). Not sure why this is, but just note that you should only save once, in onPause().